# Transferring Calls From External IVR to Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, ivr, amazon-connect

I'm currently setting up a Amazon Connect call center with a Lex bot that handles customer needs. The idea is that a prior IVR (CISCO), will transfer the call over to Amazon Connect.

Has anyone had any luck passing over any data collected/associated with the CISCO (or any other external) IVR to Amazon Connect?

I know that when transferring a call from one Amazon Connect flow to another Amazon Connect flow, a Previous Contact ID indicates the ID of the previous call, but I was wondering if the same is available when coming from an external IVR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to transfer data from an external IVR into Amazon Connect (or really any other ACD system, for that matter). What you need to do is store the data associated with the phone # in a database or other central location (preferably in AWS), and then access that data via Lambda within your Amazon Connect contact flows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box functionality available for transferring data from external IVR to Amazon Connect. However, you can transfer the call to Amazon Connect by calling connect.startOutboundVoiceContact method of Amazon Connect.

You can pass the information/data in the form of attributes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html#startOutboundVoiceContact-property

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do is claim a number of delivery numbers, Cisco would use these to deliver the voice. Cisco would call an API which uses the delivery number as a key in DynamoDB when the contact flow in Connect associated with that delivery number would read the data from the DynamoDB with a Lambda and then use the data passed.